# Posting a List<Object> payload to a razor page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a razor and on the page I'm binding to a list:

```
[BindProperty]
public List<CleanupToolMerge> MergeList { get; set; }
```

CleanupToolMerge Class:

```
public partial class CleanupToolMerge
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
    public int ItemCount { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

I initialize the list an empty object on the `OnGet` page:

```
public IActionResult OnGet()
{
    MergeList = new(); // Initialize
    return Page();
}
```

My view contains hidden inputs in order to get this object:

```
<form method="post" id="CleanupMergeForm">
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
...
<div class="form-group" id="mergeList"></div> <!-- Merge List -->
<div class="form-group">
<input type="submit" value="Preview Merge" id="prevMerge" class="btn btn-primary" />
</div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
// Cleanup previous imports Html
$('#mergeList').remove();
// Create the element
$('#CleanupMergeForm').append('<div class="form-group" id="mergeList"></div>');   
let _data = table.rows('.selected').data(); // All selected rows to merge
let _length = _data.length;
let _list = [];
console.log('Importing ' + _length + ' row(s)')

// Build array for List<CleanupToolMerge>
for (var i = 0; i < _length; i++) {
    _list.push(_data[i]);
    console.log(_data[i]);
    $("<input>").attr({
        name: "MergeList", // <------------ MergeList is created here
        id: "MergeList_" + i, // <--------- Each item to be added to the array
        type: "hidden",
        value: $(_data[i]).serialize()
    }).appendTo("#mergeList");
}
console.log('Created' + _length + ' rows to merge');
```

Razor page controller

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    if(MergeList !=null)
        Console.WriteLine("Merge Size: " + MergeList.Count); // Always 0
    return Page();
}
```

Example `.data()` object

```
{itemName: '"2"', itemId: 'e7c6e858-b5db-44ab-9ca2-df269087c24b', itemCount: 1, createdDate: '2022-03-08T15:13:52.39', modifiedDate: null}
```

The issue I am facing is I cannot seem to get the data from the posted form. I can see the data in the html as hidden inputs for `MergeList` but the array count is always 0 inside of `OnPost()`.

Comment: Please include the CleanupToolMerge class in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to bind lists or arrays, the name attribute of the input field should be `MergeList[index].PropertyName`. `index` should start with 0 in order to be bound.

You need to separate the input fields like in the code below. `ItemId` and `ItemName` must have their own input field.

```
for (var i = 0; i < _length; i++) {
   ...
   $("<input>").attr({
      name: "MergeList[i].ItemId", // ItemId
      id: "MergeList_" + i,
      type: "hidden",
      value: _data[i].ItemId // ItemId
   }).appendTo("#mergeList");

   $("<input>").attr({
      name: "MergeList[i].ItemName", // ItemName
      id: "MergeList_" + i,
      type: "hidden",
      value: _data[i].ItemName // ItemName
   }).appendTo("#mergeList");

   // add the properties item count, etc
}
```

Comment: I added the class. Do I create a `MergeList[i].prop` for each of my class properties?

Comment: @Kyle looks like you're trying to submit an entire object inside 1 input field-- we have to separate the input fields depending on how many properties are there

Comment: @Kyle also update the value attribute, I just guessed on how to get the property from _data object

Comment: Thank you so much this solves my issue. :)

Comment: @Kyle you're welcome, goodluck!